# getting weird symbol from file input

Tags: c++, arrays, file, io

I am inputing a file (input.txt) into my program 
input.txt contains this text:

```
Trojans, 0.80, 0.60
Bruins, 0.20, 0.30
Bears, 0.60, 0.50
Trees, 0.50, 0.40
Ducks, 0.40, 0.80
Beavers, 0.50, 0.10
Huskies, 0.80, 0.40
Cougars, 0.10, 0.90
```

but what is outputed in terminal is

```
Trojans, 0.80, 0.60
Bruins, 0.20, 0.30
Bears, 0.60, 0.50
Trees, 0.50, 0.40
Ducks, 0.40, 0.80
Beavers, 0.50, 0.10
Huskies, 0.80, 0.40
Cougars, 0.10, 0.90�
```

I am not sure where the weird question mark is coming from.

my code currently is

any idea why that might be the case?

Comment: ifstream_obj.get() obtains one character at a time, which you're storing in a character array.  This array will look to C++ like an old c-style array, and consequently, should be null-terminated.  Also, your input buffer (team) is not large enough; you're running past the end of the array, and invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: See the example here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/

Comment: oh that makes alot of sense, so if i just included a if statement telling the program to break when it reaches eof?

Comment: That's inadequate.  You are creating a c-string, but not null-terminating it.  You are also reading more characters into that string than the size of the array allocated to receive them.

Comment: would this be an issue later on when i am taking data from this array, even though i tell the program to stop reading in values once it reaches eof.

Comment: im also still a little confused by what you mean

Comment: team variable's length seems not enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eof() tells you whether you have attempted to read past end of file, so your loop is not correct. It should be:

```
for (;;)
{
    temp = myfile.get();
    if (myfile.eof()) break;
    team[il] = temp;
    il++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Last charecter is some junk value. Because il is incremented in the while loop even when it is at EOF. Below change should correct the problem.  Check the change for condition to  nee < (il -1 )

```
  for (int nee = 0; nee < (il - 1); nee++) //check to see if what i outputted is correct
    {
        cout << team[nee];
    }
```

Check the modified readfile routine below:

```
void readfile()
    {   
        char temp;
        ifstream myfile ("input.txt");
        int il = 0;
        while (!myfile.eof())
        {   
            temp = myfile.get();
            team[il] = temp;
            il++;
        }   
        for (int nee = 0; nee < il - 1; nee++) //check to see if what i outputted is correct
        {   
            cout << team[nee];
        }   
        cout << endl ;
    }
```

Comment: thank you, but do you know how i can get rid of that junk value from storing into my array?

Comment: You may memset the array to have '\0' chars. But the program should print only the chars it read

Comment: yeah thats the huge issue it's still reading in this random question mark

Answer (score 0):

`myfile.eof()` will return true **after** the first read that fails, in your read loop

```
temp = myfile.get();
team[il] = temp;
il++;
```

you read a byte with `myfile.get()` which *will fail at the end of the file*, but you do not check that you successfully read a byte from the file. The easiest way to correct this is to insert a check *after* `myfile.get()` but before you do anything with the result.

```
temp = myfile.get();
if(!myfile) // use implicit conversion from stream to bool to test for success
    break;
team[il] = temp;
il++;
```

This isn't a particularly elegant loop construct though, personally I would use something like this:

```
for(char temp=myfile.get(); 
    myfile && il < sizeof(team)/sizeof(team[0]); 
    temp=myfile.get(), ++il)
{
    team[il] = temp;
}
```

This will work because the loop condition (`myfile`) will be checked after each get, but before the body of the loop (`team[il] = temp;`) is executed, so there is no danger of your writing an invalid character to `team`.

Note that your code contains a potential buffer overrun if myfile is more than 80 bytes in length, I've added a condition in the loop above that ensures the routine will stop reading at the end of the file or 80 bytes - whichever occurs first.

Comment: His script also fails to terminate the c-string "team" with a \0, so cout will continue printing until it bumps into one.

Comment: I agree, it should be null terminated - but he's actually outputting the characters one by one so can get away with not null terminating if for some bizarre reason he wants to!